# Rename a mongodb collection in php

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I am trying to do this in php

```
$m = $this->mongo_db->db->selectCollection("admin");
$this->mongo_db->db->command(array('renameCollection'=> 'dbname'.$old_grpname,'to'=>'dbname'.$group_name));
```

I am using codeigniter... this is not working neither its throwing any exception
where i am going wrong ??

also is there a way to use mongodb's `renameCollection()` function in php..
i looked it out and found nothing

Edit:
I should connect to the admin database and try to rename a collection
so i did so now i am getting this error

```
array(3) {
  ["ok"]=>
  float(0)
  ["errmsg"]=>
  string(146) "not authorized on admin to execute command { renameCollection: "dbname.wp_content", to: "dbname.wp_content123", dropTarget: "true" }"
  ["code"]=>
  int(13)
}
```

i guess there is some problem with roles for admin but i have given all privileges to admin while creating user
the command i used was this

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

thanks :)

Comment: i visited the link earlier and now i am aware that i should do this from admin db so i logged in to admin and now i am getting this error "not authorized on admin to execute command " i have given all roles properly